# Formatted drive recovery

Tags: restore

My ubuntu 14.04 got stuck at login and asking for password again and again. I reset my OS and a very important folder from desktop got deleted. Is there any way I could restore it.

Please reply ASAP.

Thanks,
Jyoti Jha

Comment: Have you reinstalled fully?

Comment: I dnt knw i am new to.this OS

Comment: You have mentioned "I reset my OS" can you explain what steps you have done.

Comment: Started the syatem...pressed f12...there were 2 options under boot options..ubuntu and something with toshiba i selected the later one and system did smthn...it asked for time zone , pc name , username password i just followed the steps

Comment: I think you reinstalled the OS. If that is the case chances are very very less to recover the folder.

Answer (score 9):

When you say you "reset" you OS, I assume you mean you re-installed. You can try using a variety of recovery options, but be warned they are all a bit complex.

There is no absolute guarantee you can get the data back. Don't let that discourage you, though. If the data has not been overwritten and if you are able to use the tools well enough, it is very likely that it will be possible.

### Important Info

When you realize that you've lost data and you need to recover it, the first and most important step is to **stop using the drive entirely**. Don't even boot up the OS on the affected drive. **The deleted data can get overwritten just by using the drive, and if that happens you will not be able to recover it**.

**Don't do anything at all to the drive until you are sure of what you are doing.** Just clicking things and trying every random suggestion you see online is a really good way to irrecoverably overwrite your data. **Recovering files is a sensitive task and impatience is your worst enemy.**

**Don't panic.** This goes along with what was said above. Panicking can cause you to rush and do things without being sure they are safe. Calm down and approach the task with a level head.

**Do recovery work from an Ubuntu live cd** or by attaching the drive to another machine for recovery (do not mount the drive).

It is always best to **do recovery work on an image of your drive instead of on the drive itself**. Some data recovery operations can cause irreversible changes, so if you make a mistake on an image you can just start again with a fresh image. If you have a large empty drive you can use to make a backup image of the drive on, that would be best.

Also, when you are recovering deleted files, you must **write the recovered files to a different drive than the one you are recovering from**, or else you risk overwriting the deleted files in the process.

**If you use an encrypted home folder, recovery will be even more difficult.** I have not yet attempted this myself, but I think you would have to recover every deleted file in the encrypted home folder (which may be the entire home folder in your case), and then use `ecryptfs-recover-private` to unlock the encrypted folder (using the password it was originally encrypted with) and search for the files you need.

### Possible ways to recover your data

(This entire section assumes you are running from an Ubuntu live disc or another recovery machine. As stated above, do not boot your computer from the affected drive.)

#### Making an image of the drive

If you have enough space on another drive to make an image of the affected drive, do that first. Use the command `dd` to do this. You will need to know the device name of your drive (for example /dev/sda). Avoid mounting the drive while you are trying to determine which device it is. Write the image to another drive that has space (this will take a long time, depending on the size of your drive it could be several hours).

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/[destination location]/image.dd`

#### TestDisk

I would recommend that you start your recovery attempt with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

`sudo apt-get install testdisk`

Start testdisk on the drive image you created earlier.

`sudo testdisk /[location]/image.dd`

If you don't have an image file, use testdisk on the drive directly. For example, if the drive is `/dev/sda` use the following command:

`sudo testdisk /dev/sda`

TestDisk will ask if you want to make a log file. This is usually a good idea. Either make a new one, or append to a previous one.

If you didn't start TestDisk with a specific drive or image, you will next be asked which drive you want to work on. In that case, select the drive from the list.

TestDisk should automatically detect your partition table type and suggest it to you. Use the suggested type, or if it doesn't offer a suggestion try selecting `[Intel]` from the list.

Next you will see the tools menu.  Select `[Analyse]` and then do a `[Quick Search]` on the next screen. Wait for a while as TestDisk looks through the superblocks of your partitions and finds current and deleted files.

If you reinstalled Ubuntu, then your old partition table probably got overwritten and Quick Search will not reveal the partition you are looking for. However, you should look through the partitions it found first just to check. Partitions listed in green are the partitions in the current partition table. White partitions are old entries which have been removed from the table (you probably won't see any white after a Quick Search).

If you used a standard install, there should be a Linux Swap and a data partition. Highlight the data partition and press P to `List Files`. Use the arrow keys to navigate through folders and look for your missing files. (The Right arrow will go inside a folder, the Left arrow goes back up to the parent folder.) Deleted files will be listed in red. If you find what you are looking for, copy the files out using the instructions at the bottom. You must copy the files out to a different drive (not the one you are recovering from).

If you can't find what you are looking for in that partition (because the reinstall wrote new partitions), you will need to do a deeper search. Press the q key until you get back to the screen where you originally chose `Quick Search`. The Quick Search option will be gone, and you will now see `Deeper Search`. Use the Deeper Search and wait a while as it finds all current and old partition table entries. Now search through the File Listings on the old partition entries as you did above. It is possible that the Deeper Search may find hundreds of "partitions" that actually contain nothing (they will say something like "No filesystem" or the like when you try to list files), so it may take some time to find the old partition you are looking for. Try to find one that has the right size characteristics. Hopefully you will find your files this way and you can copy them out to a different drive.

#### PhotoRec

If you are not able to find the files using TestDisk, you can try using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). PhotoRec will recover all of the deleted files on a drive, but it will not recover the filenames, so you will have quite a task to sort through them finding what you need. It helps if you know the filetype of the lost files, since PhotoRec will tell you what type of file it recovered (it recognizes over 300 file types). You will need a hard drive with enough free space to write the recovered files to.

Install PhotoRec

`sudo apt-get install photorec`

Then start PhotoRec with the drive image.

`sudo photorec /[location]/image.dd`

Once you've started PhotoRec, you can use the `[File Opt]` option to limit what type of files you want to recover (this is useful if you know what you're looking for).

When you are ready, choose `[Search]` and select your filesystem type. Ubuntu Linux is usually ext3 or ext4, unless you know that you used a different filesystem.

PhotoRec may offer you the option of searching free space or the whole drive (it didn't offer me this option). If you get this option, you probably just want to search free space.

Next, choose where the recovered files should be written to. **Be absolutely sure to choose a location that is not on the affected drive.** When you are ready, press the C key to begin file recovery.

As mentioned above, the files that PhotoRec recovers will not have filenames. You will need to look through them to find what you are looking for, and depending on the number of files recovered this could be a very time consuming task.

#### A Note on Encrypted Files

If the files you are recovering were in an encrypted folder, they will be recovered as ecryptfs encrypted files, and you will need to use the normal method of decrypting ecryptfs files using the password with which they were encrypted. I am not going to go into how to do that in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot from a live usb or dvd of Ubuntu, mount your old drives, and then recover the file. However, the file will not be there if by 'reset' you mean that you reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: I inserted usb drive when it asked for recovery backup...and it wrote something in it...can it be helpful

Comment: Connect and check that drive.

Comment: When did it ask for recovery backup? You can post useful info at pastebin.org and put the link here to show us.