# Accidentally reformatted a data drive using the "disk" utility

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I did something extremely stupid: I reformatted my 2TB extra drive when I wanted to reformat my 16GB thumb drive. The good news is:

- The drive I reformatted did not contain my /home or root directory, so the OS is still working fine
- I didn't write anything to it, nor did I check the "force overwrite all data" option

There are a lot of tutorials for how to fix this out there, none of them fit my exact situation. I do not have the ability to back this drive up as it is 2TB. Please help me!

Comment: If you can't back this up and the data is very important, you should probably take it to experts to deal with. Whatever you try has the possibility of making the data even harder to recover.

Comment: Of course hiring an expert would be ideal, but such an expert would charge a few hundred at minimum and I'd rather not do that if it's an easy fix.

Comment: Actually a few thousands as a retainer is the standard practice.

Comment: You can try the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865834/formatted-drive-recovery), either should apply in your case. But be aware that you might ruin any chance of recovering the data in the process, so if the data is worth the cost of professional recovery that might be a better option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/a/1411495/1598467

Comment: No, because I think that the directory structure might be recoverable since there is still a copy of the GPT somewhere on the disk.

Comment: Take a look at TestDisk, I think it can do that if there's enough data left.

Comment: Running a testdisk scan right now, it takes hours

Comment: Correct: The scan may take hours. And the scan is just the first, easiest step. Folks who want to try their hand at data-recovery must be patient. must be prepared for frustration, and must expect to discover new and interesting puzzles along the path.